# Hive 'create table like' without including partition columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

Say I create tbl1 like so:

```
create table tbl1 (
    col_a STRING,
    col_b STRING,
    col_c STRING )
partitioned by (col_d STRING);
```

Is there a shorthand way to create tbl2 - a table with same columns as tbl1, but without paritioning by anything (and without including the parition column). tbl2 manual ddl would be:

```
create table tbl2 (
    col_a STRING,
    col_b STRING,
    col_c STRING );
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: use describe tableName command; edit output: cut partition info

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTAS(Create table as Select) in hive.

```
create table tbl2 as select * from tbl1
```

This will not create any partition in tbl2 even though the tbl1 holds the partition.Only limitation is with out select you cannot be able to create the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioned column also one of the columns in the table.
if you want only 3 columns(col_a, col_b, col_c), you need to explicitly mention them in the query answered by Avinash.

```
create table tbl2 as select col_a, col_b, col_c from tbl1;
```